# What would be a good way to set and get cookies in Vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3, auth0

I am relatively new to Vue 3. I am using Auth0 for authenticating users. For now, I am keeping managing organisations within my database. I would like to retrieve organisation Id for the user and store it in a cookie for the application to access it.

I have created a composable to manage cookies

```
import { inject } from 'vue'
import type { VueCookies } from 'vue-cookies'

export default function useCookies() {
  const $cookies = inject<VueCookies>('$cookies')

  async function setCookies(orgId: string) {
    $cookies?.set('orgId', orgId, '1y')
  }

  async function getCookies() {
    return $cookies?.get('orgId')
  }

  async function removeCookies() {
    $cookies?.remove('orgId')
  }

  return { setCookies, getCookies, removeCookies }
}
```

Initially, I would set cookie when a user is authenticated. At the moment, I am thinking do it in "LoginButton.vue" component.

```
<template>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" @click="handleLogin">Log In</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-vue'

const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0()

const handleLogin = () => {
  loginWithRedirect({
    appState: {
      targetUrl: '/about'
    }
  })
}

</script>
```

My plan is to get orgId from cookie on "onMounted" when a user goes to a page. If the cookie has expired, then set it and get the value for use.

I am unsure if it is the best plan but any guidance from the experienced people would be much appreciated.